# Upper bound on exact power of wild prime that divides the different

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ramification

Let $K$ be a number field and let $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ be a prime. Suppose that $p\mathcal{O}_K=Q^eI$, with $\gcd(Q, I)=1$ and let $\mathcal{D}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}$ be the different ideal of $K$. We know that $Q^{e-1}\mid \mathcal{D}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}$ and if $Q$ is tamely ramified over $p$, i.e. $p\not\mid e$, then $Q^e\not\mid \mathcal{D}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}$. Suppose now that $Q$ is wild over $p$, i.e. $p\mid e$, and let $k$ be the exact power of $Q$ that divides $\mathcal{D}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}$. If we know $p$ and $e$, can we give an upper bound on $k$?

Comment: A cool question! I am a novice in this area and more familiar with the function field side anyway, so I am surprised that there actually could be an upper bound! Consider the following function field example. Let $k$ be a finite field of characteristic two, $F=k(x)$, and $K=F(y)$, with $y^2+y=x^{2t+1}$. The non-trivial element of the Galois group $Gal(K/F)$ is given by $\sigma(y)=y+1$. The infinite place of $F$ is totally ramified, so for the sole valuation $\nu$ above it we have $\nu(x)=-2$, $\nu(y)=-(2t+1)$. Hence $\alpha=y/x^{t+1}$ is a local parameter.

Comment: (cont'd) But
$$\sigma(\alpha)-\alpha=\frac1{x^{t+1}}$$
has value $2(t+1)$. Because we can let $t$ be arbitrarily large, this implies that there is no upper bound in terms of $p=e=2$ such that the higher ramification groups would become trivial. Consequently we get arbitrarily high different exponents. It is clear that nothing of this sort can happen with e.g. a quadratic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$, I just never thought about there being this kind of a difference in behavior.

Comment: Yes, @JyrkiLahtonen, I think the local case of the following extension of $\Bbb F_p((t))$ also shows this interesting difference from the mixed-characteristic case. Let $\pi$ be a root of $X^p+t^nX+t$. I suppose it shows how there are separable elements arbitrarily close to the inseparable element $t^{1/p}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is an upper bound depending only on $p$ and $e=p^n$, and it’s achieved in the extension $K=\Bbb Q(p^{1/e})$.

This is a purely local question, and I’m going to pretend that you asked it for wildly ramified extensions of $\Bbb Q_p$, though the translation to $\Bbb Q$ is almost automatic. First let’s look at the above extension:

We have $\pi$, a root of $X^{p^n}-p$, whose derivative is $p^nX^{p^n-1}$, substitute $\pi$ and get $p^n\pi^{p^n-1}=\delta$, a number with $v_\pi(\delta)=np^n+p^n-1=(n+1)e-1$. I say that this is as big as your number $k$ can get.

Our general extension $K\supset\Bbb Q_p$ is to be totally wildly ramified, so of degree $p^n=e$, with a prime element $\pi$ that’s root of an Eisenstein polynomial $F(X)\in\Bbb Q_p[X]$. Say $F=X^{p^n}+\sum_0^{e-1} c_jX^j$, with $\delta=F'(\pi)=p^n\pi^{p^n-1}+\sum_0^{p^n-2}(j+1)c_{j+1}\pi^j$. When you ask for the $v_\pi$-value of this, you notice that no two monomials in the expression have the same value, since all are incongruent modulo $p^n=e$: the numbers $v_\pi(c_{j+1})$ are in $\Bbb Q_p$ and thus are divisible by $e=p^n$. So the minimum of the $v_\pi$-values of these monomials may well be less than that of $p^n\pi^{p^n-1}$, but since this monomial might also dominate, as it did in my example, that is the biggest possible value for $k$.